# curl not working,not show any output

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.example.com";   
$data = array(
    "email" => "vicky@gg.com",
    "firstname" => "firstname",
    "lastname" => "lastname",
    "password1" => "123456",
    "password2" => "123456",
    "key" => "d12121c70dda5edfgd1df6633fdb3"
);                                                                    

$data_string = json_encode($data);   

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$output = json_decode($result,true);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [curl_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)? You may find a problem with the https: protocol.

Comment: curl_error shows
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

to disable SSL check.